# Maven profile properties not overriding values in springs configurations

Tags: maven, profile, activation

I have a very weird problem with maven profiles.

In pom.xml we have profiles with some properties. We use those properties on pom.xml and in spring configurations. When building with specific profile only properties in pom.xml are affected, in spring configurations there are the defaults. Somehow it seems that profile isn't activated, althought properties in pom.xml are changed.

When I activate profile default like this:

```
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
</activation>
```

All properties are changed as those should.

I run maven form command line and I'm using version 3.0.4 from Ubuntu 12.04 repositories. I also tested with standalone 3.0.5 version. Command I use:

```
mvn clean package -P profile-id
```

If this isn't weird enough, I'm only one who have this problem in this project so it has to be something with my computer, I just don't know where to look at.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is bug in maven-resources-plugin versions 2.5 and 2.6. We fixed this issue by specifying version to 2.4.